# Return list from Graphql resolve

Tags: react-native, mongoose, callback, graphql, graphql-js

```
fetchFriends: {
  type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
  args: {
    currentId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
  },
  resolve: (_, {currentId}) => {
    return Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        User.findById(currentId, (err, users) => {
          users.getFriends((err, user) => {
            console.log(user);
            return user;
          });
        });
      })

  }
  /* another version what i tried that returns only the initial findById user 
    resolve: (_, {currentId}) => {
    var value = User.findById(currentId, (err, user) => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        user.getFriends((err, user) => {
          console.log('fetch: ', user);
          err ? reject(err) : resolve(user)
        });
      })
    })
    return value;
  }*/
},
```

I have a graphql resolve that i am getting the User object within the findById callback. that specific object calls getFriends which is a part of a mongoose plugin (friends-of-friends) and the console.log within getFriends callback contains the list in the terminal so i know getFriends 
 is returning the proper data but i cannot figure out how to return the value into my React-Native Component. i have tried for the past 8 hours everything i can think of and cannot get the value returned out of this function.

Comment: Have you tried using state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but there's a couple of things to keep in mind when working with resolvers:

- Your resolver has to return **either** a value that matches the type/scalar specified in your schema **or** a Promise that will resolve to that value.
- Mongoose operations [can return a promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), and you should utilize this feature of them rather than trying to wrap callbacks inside Promises as this can easily get messy
- Return statements inside callbacks at least in this context) don't actually do anything. Return statements inside a `then`, on the other hand, determine what the promise will resolve to (or what promise to invoke next in the chain).

I would imagine your resolver needs to look something like this:

```
resolve (_, {currentId}) => {
  // calling exec() on the query turns it into a promise
  return User.findById(currentId).exec()
    // the value the promise resolves to is accessible in the "then" method
    .then(user => {
      // should make sure user is not null here, something like:
      if (!user) return Promise.reject(new Error('no user found with that id'))
      // we want the value returned by another async method, getFriends, so
      // wrap that call in a promise, and return the promise
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        user.getFriends((error, friends) => {
          if (error) reject(error)
          resolve(friends)
        })
      })
    })
}
```